# ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [labels (MUST BE IN THE INDEX)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove duplicates from one dataframe from other with this:

```
frame = frame.loc[frame.index.difference(properties.index), ]
```

But I`m receiving this error:

```
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [labels (MUST BE IN THE INDEX), slices of labels (BOTH endpoints included! Can be slices of integers if the index is integers), listlike of labels, boolean] types
```

This is frame.index:

```
>>> frame.index
Index([ u'(11) 4451-5818', u'(11) 96949-2162',  u'(11) 5536-5052',
        u'(11) 5084-1481',  u'(11) 3846-6720',  u'(11) 3067-4424',
        u'(11) 3256-5330',  u'(11) 5181-4004',  u'(11) 3078-0760',
        u'(11) 3152-6111',
       ...
        u'(11) 2541-7538',  u'(11) 2057-7777',  u'(11) 3283-0473',
        u'(11) 2231-3614',  u'(11) 5615-6101',  u'(11) 2242-4927',
        u'(11) 2849-7040',  u'(11) 2456-4342',  u'(11) 2541-0284',
        u'(11) 3051-5881'],
      dtype='object', name=u'phone', length=18039)

>>> properties.index
Index([u'(01) 13562-7550', u'(11) 5051-1959', u'(11) 3052-1878',
       u'(11) 3849-5839', u'(11) 3203-0996', u'(11) 3258-2578',
       u'(11) 3051-4545', u'(11) 5542-1680', u'(11) 3159-8889',
       u'(11) 3283-2349',
       ...
       u'(11) 2305-2200', u'(18) 997389999', u'(11) 3868-4884',
       u'(11) 3259-0932', u'(11) 3081-2158', u'(11) 3034-6500',
       u'(11) 5082-4308', u'(11) 34346467', u'', u'(11) 31923858'],
      dtype='object', name=u'phone', length=1279)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That error message could use some work. I was slightly annoyed when I saw your title using CAPS but apparently it's an actual error :/

Comment: if you do `frame = frame[frame.index.difference(properties.index)]` what happens?

Comment: @Yuca I receive this error: ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: interesting, result should be only indexes, not NA

Answer (score 0):

I removed the duplicates and nulls from frame and it's working now